# capistrano-git configuration is changing hosts

Tags: git, capistrano

My provider (dreamhost) changed servers on me.  My cap deploy:migrations command is now giving me grief.  It uses the new servername everywhere except when it asks for my password.

> Instead of
>
> username@servername.dreamhost.com
>
> It uses
>
> username@oldservername.dreamhost.com

A sanitized version of the outputs is below.

```
d@d-laptop:~/projectname$ cap deploy:migrations   
* executing `deploy:migrations'   
* executing `deploy:update_code'
        updating the cached checkout on all servers
        executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://username@servername.dreamhost.com/~/repos/projectname/ master"   * executing "if [ -d /home/username/servername..../shared/cached-copy ]; then ... fi"
        servers: ["url"]
        [streamline.ruil-project.net] executing command  

** [streamline.ruil-project.net :: out]

username@OLDServerName.dreamhost.com's password:
```

Is the user name being stored in ssh-keygen that git or capistrano is relying on?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy using capistrano there is a git repository called cached-copy placed on the server.  If your server gets switched from (old.dreamhost.com) to (new.dreamhost.com), then you need to make sure to update the git settings to reflect this in cached-copy.